# How to add a border to an item in a ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, border, itemscontrol

I am trying to set a border to each item from a items control. Following is my XAML code. But this doesn't work.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Control.BorderThickness" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="Control.BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The container in an `ItemsControl` is a `ContentPresenter` which is **not** a control, this style will not do anything. You could create an [`ItemsTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) containing a `Border`.

Alternatively you can change the `ContentTemplate` in the `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="5">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

(Note: This is a real alternative in the sense that *it does the exact same thing*, so i would use the `ItemTemplate` as it is a lot less verbose, saves you three tags (`Style`, `Setter`, `Setter.Value`))

Comment: By "the exact same thing", H.B. means that `ItemsControl.ItemsTemplate` sets the `ContentTemplate` of each item container. This means that if you do both, the `ItemTemplate` will completely replace the `ItemContainerStyle`'s `ContentTemplate` value.

Answer (score 2):

See the remarks on [`BorderThickness`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.control.borderthickness.aspx) and `[BorderBrush][1]`:

> This property only affects a control whose template uses the BorderThickness property as a parameter.On other controls, this property has no impact.
>
> This property only affects a control whose template uses the BorderBrush property as a parameter.On other controls, this property has no impact.

So you actually need such a control, e.g. [Border](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.controls.border.aspx) in which you wrap whatever you need to display.